# Read package.json version inside package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a `package.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t myapp .",
    "docker-run": "docker run -d --name myapp -p 9090:9090 myapp",
    "docker-push": "docker build -t myapp . & docker tag myapp myrepo/myapp:{$VERSION} & docker push myrepo/myapp:{$VERSION}"
  },
... 
}
```

Im trying to get the version number when I run `npm run docker-push` so it will automatically tag the release with the version number of the `package.json`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reference package version in npm script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609931/how-can-i-reference-package-version-in-npm-script)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the environment variable `npm_package_version`.

**Tip:** To see all available environment variables set by npm you can add "printenv | grep npm" as a script:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "version": "echo ${npm_package_version}", // return current version
    "vars": "printenv | grep npm" // return all ENV vars with 'npm'
  }
  // ...
}
```