# How can I reference package version in npm script?

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I want to reference my package version in a npm script so I can show current version in the app.
Something like

```json
{
  "name": "bla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "bla bla",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node VERSION=<<package.version>> build/build.js"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

#### 1) Referencing package version in npm-scripts.

In `npm-script`'s you can reference the `version` using the variable `npm_package_version`. For example:

- **Using a bash shell (E.g. Linux, macOS):**

  ```json
  {
    ...
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "echo $npm_package_version"
    }
  }
  ```

  *Note the `$` prefix*
- **Using Windows (E.g. cmd.exe, Powershell):**

  ```json
  {
    ...
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "echo %npm_package_version%"
    }
  }
  ```

  *Note the `%` prefix and suffix*
- **Cross platform**

  To utilize one syntax cross-platform check out the package [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var)

---

#### 2) Referencing package version in node script.

The package version can also be referenced in your a app/node script (i.e. `build.js`) as follows:

```js
const VERSION = process.env.npm_package_version;
console.log(VERSION); // --> 1.0.0
```

---

#### 3) Replacing a placeholder string in a .js file with package version.

Another way to achieve this is to specify a placeholder text string within your JavaScript file. Lets say we have a file named `build.js` and within that file we have a variable named `VERSION` declared as follows:

```js
// build.js
const VERSION = '@VERSION@'
```

As you can see, the placeholder text string is `@VERSION@`.

You can then install and utilize the package called [replace](https://github.com/harthur/replace) in an [npm-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) as follows:

```json
{
  ...
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "add-version":  "replace -s \"@VERSION@\" $npm_package_version build/build.js"
  }
}
```

Running `npm run add-version` will replace the instance of `@VERSION@` with the package version (i.e. `1.0.0`), in the file named `build.js`. This solution will hard-code the npm package version into the resultant file.

Note: The *to* string in the `add-version` script (above) currently uses the `$` prefix (i.e. `$npm_package_version`) to access the variable, so this will only run successfully on a bash shell. However, for cross-platform usage you'll need to use `cross-var` as explained in section one (above). In which case the `add-version` script can be defined as follows:

```json
{
  ...
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "add-version":  "cross-var replace -s \"@VERSION@\" $npm_package_version build/build.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice summary.  Many other npm variables are available -- see https://gist.github.com/moos/4635bda5b04dc8113d8ea7ee974cabc2.

Comment: @Moos -  To programmatically list all _`npm_`_ environment variables that are specific to your project you can utilize the `npm run env` command - as described in my answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59172784/command-to-list-all-npm-package-vars/59174920#59174920).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **"run-script-os"** npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-script-os)

example:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "zip": "run-os",
    "zip:macos": "7z a ./build/my.bible.com-$npm_package_version.zip views manifest.json README.md",
    "zip:windows": "7z a ./build/my.bible.com-%npm_package_version%.zip views manifest.json README.md",
  }
}
```

then simply run `npm run zip` from any OS.