# How do I get current package's version using only npm

Tags: node.js, npm

How do I get the current version from package.json using `npm`?

I know that `npm version` will output my package's version along with npm and other dependencies. But I need a short command to get only my package version to use on a CI. So ideally, no extra input as the CI doesn't know what project it's dealing with.

`npm version from-git --allow-same-version` would also work, if it didn't try to tag the new version on Git.

Comment: You'll need to utilize either an npm script or nodejs script as _npm_ does not provide a direct command to achieve this. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609931/how-can-i-reference-package-version-in-npm-script#answer-48619640) which indicates how to reference npm's built-in variable named `npm_package_version` to retrieve the current version from _package.json_.

Comment: no accepted answer?

Answer (score 28):

Using npm:

`npm -s run env echo '$npm_package_version'`

from npm v7.2:

`npm pkg get version`

Comment: These commands also make it really easy to get other package properties, such as `name` with `npm -s run env echo '$npm_package_name'` or `npm pkg get name`. Note that the `npm pkg get` command return values include surrounding quotes.

Comment: Both commands are not working for me.

Comment: It could also be used as shebang in external scripts (they may even resides in another fs location): `#!/usr/bin/env -S npm -s run env bash` (and you can replace bash with python, node, ...).

Comment: This command has a long delay, I prefere ben's answer

Comment: OPs wanted something that works with npm, Ben's answer doesn't fulfill those constraints

Answer (score 22):

There is no direct npm command to show only your package version, but you can use this hack from your project folder:

```
node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').version);"
```

If you want to use an npm command you can wrap it into a "script" in your `package.json` file :

```
"scripts": {
    "version": "node -e console.log(require('./package.json').version);"
}
```

Now you can launch `npm run version` to get your package version

Comment: This is better than a hack.

Comment: you can actually npm without adding a new script to get the version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65392808/747749

Comment: I upvoted this one instead of `npm pkg get version` because this is much more performant.

Answer (score 11):

To build on Kaz's answer this is slightly shorter.

```sh
PACKAGE_VERSION=`node -p "require('./package.json').version"`
```

Comment: This is really the fastest answer compared to `npm pkg get version`

Answer (score 1):

If using `grep` and `sed` is not a problem for you, this is working pretty good for me:

```sh
VERSION_NUMBER=$(npm version | grep @ | sed -re "s/\{ '.*': '(.*)',?/\1/g")
```

Explanations:

- `npm version` gives you all the information
- `grep @` catches the line where you have the version
- `sed -re "s/\{ '.*': '(.*)',?/\1/g"` replaces the text by just the version number

Answer (score 0):

If your project is backed by git and you are letting `npm version` tag your builds, you can probably leverage `git describe`:

```
echo The current build is \"`git describe`\". 
==> The current build is "v0.0.2".
```

It's not *technically* using `npm` to get the version, but it's what I ended up using after trying to find a 'real' `npm` based solution and finding this SO that makes it quite clear that there isn't a nice clean command available.