# Command to list all npm_package_vars

Tags: npm

Is there a command to list all the `npm_package_var` variables?

I know individually we can get the vars using npm_package_var syntax.

Is there a command that I can use to list *all* these vars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** npm does not provide a built-in command that does exactly what you need. However, it can list all variables. For instance:

1. Firstly, `cd` to your project directory.
2. Then run the following command to list all variables:

   ```
   npm run env
   ```

The [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script#description) states the following about the `env` script:

> The `env` script is a special built-in command that can be used to list environment variables that will be available to the script at runtime. If an “env” command is defined in your package, it will take precedence over the built-in.

---

### Solution:

To list the [`npm_package_vars`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) only, consider piping the result of the aforementioned `npm run env` command to either; [`grep`](https://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) if using **nix*, or to [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) if using Windows.

For instance, firstly `cd` to your project directory then run either of the following compound commands - depending on which OS you're using:

- On  **nix* platforms run the following:

  ```
  npm run env | grep ^npm_package_
  ```
- Or, on Windows run the following instead:

  ```
  npm run env | findstr /B npm_package_
  ```

---

**Note (Git For Windows):**

If you're using [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) (i.e. if you're using [git-bash](/questions/tagged/git-bash) as your preferred command line) then I recommend utilizing the aforementioned `grep` command:

```
npm run env | grep ^npm_package_
```

However if for some reason you wanted to use `findstr` instead of `grep`, (when using git-bash), you'll need to replace the `/B` option with `-B` instead. For instance:

```
npm run env | findstr -B npm_package_
```

Or, if that fails, then try using two forward slashes instead. For instance:

```
npm run env | findstr //B npm_package_
```

<sub>**Btw.** The `/B` option matches a pattern if it's at the beginning of a line. This is analogous to the caret `^` in GREP.`</sub>