# How to fetch package version and date in npm script?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a package.json file and I have this script to create 2 separate files one for version and other one for date.

When i run the command, it generates the `version-npm.txt` with correct data holding the current version, but the version.txt file is generated with the exact script instead, it contains `date +"%d/%m/%Y %T"`

```
"scripts": {
    "versions": "node -e \"console.log(require('./package.json').version);\" > ./public/version-npm.txt && echo `date +\"%d/%m/%Y %T\"` > ./public/version.txt" 
}
```

I need this to be updated with the current date and time. is there any other way to it or can you help me fix it?

i tried writing the date as `\"$(date)\"` still the same, now i get `\"$(date)\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is it not working?

- The way that you are obtaining the date, i.e. `date +\"%d/%m/%Y %T\"` or similarly using `\"$(date)\"` does work successfully on **nix* platforms, whereby npm utilizes `sh` by default to run npm scripts.
- However, the aforementioned method does not work on Windows because npm on that OS utilizes `cmd` as the default shell to run npm scripts - `cmd` simply does not understand the [`date`](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html) command.

---

#### Solution

The following solution will work cross-platforms (Windows, Linux, MacOS etc) :

1. Firstly `cd` to your project directory and install the [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment) package by running the following command:

   ```
   npm i -D moment
   ```

   We'll utilize this package to obtain the date/time formatted as `DD/MM/YYY HH:MM:SS`.
2. Then redefine your `versions` script in the `scripts` section of your *package.json* as follows:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "versions": "node -p \"process.env.npm_package_version\" > ./public/version-npm.txt && node -p \"require('moment')().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')\" > ./public/version.txt"
   }
   ```

**Explanation:**

1. The npm script (above) utilizes the nodejs command line option [`-p`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script) to evaluate and print the result of the following inline JavaScript:

   ```js
   process.env.npm_package_version
   ```

   This essentially utilizes nodejs [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_env) to read the environment variable `npm_package_version` which npm creates. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48609931/how-can-i-reference-package-version-in-npm-script/48619640#48619640) for further explanation.

   The version is then redirected (`>`) to the file using the same method as per your attempt:

   ```
   > ./public/version-npm.txt
   ```

   ---

   **Note**: You could continue to utilize your current, more verbose, solution to obtain the version from *package.json* if you prefer, i.e.

   ```
   node -e \"console.log(require('./package.json').version);\"
   ```

   ---
2. Next we obtain the date. Again we utilize the nodejs command line option `-p` to evaluate and print the result of the following inline JavaScript:

   ```js
   require('moment')().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
   ```

   The date value is redirected (`>`) to the file as follows:

   ```
   > ./public/version.txt
   ```

Comment: **Note:** If your are using an early version of node.js then you may encounter errors with `moment`. In which case install an earlier version. For example run `npm i -D moment@1.7.2` instead of `npm i -D moment`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and you explained it very well :)